# Webpack/React/ Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when module.id

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am getting a bizarre error and I can't find any resolution it.

Fresh react project with a local module linked via package.json link: protocol as followed.

```
"dependencies": {
    "otrm": "link:../otrm",
```

Everything runs smooth - compilation of the source module works and module dependencies are all installed .

`yarn start` ends up in this:

[image]

Now the error is pretty straight forward:

[image]

`module.id` not defined in my external library. Looking at the debugger the id is really not there.

[image]

Now the question begs, how the heck can I add the ID or what did I do wrong? I looked across the forums and Gitlab docs and the most I can find are around Angular apps .. so Stackoverflow you are my last hope.

Comment: Error comes from your chunk file, what you have is that you are trying to get some id of undefined, you need to find it and log it in the console you will see that before your object goes to the page it is undefined. Assign it to an empty object or add some if statements

Comment: Yeah I know that but why??? I actually debugged step by step and `module` becomes null at the point when it tries to assign react-refresh...

Comment: I did one more thing and published it on npm. It worked without issues. I compared the npm published code to the locally built one. There's no difference. But locally it does not work even after manually just repointing the symlink.. I wonder if this is the actual issue having a symlink.